# xpath of WMTSGetCapabilities

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I'm trying to import this XML
https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/EPSG/2056/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml
into google spreadsheets using the IMPORTXML function . using XPATH I would like
to extract from

```
...
<Layer>
<ows:Title>Städte und Agglomerationen BeSA</ows:Title>
<ows:Abstract>Die Liste der Beitragsberechtigten Städte und Agglomerationen bildet ab, welche Gemeinden im Rahmen des Programms Agglomerationsverkehr für Beiträge des Bundes beitragsberechtigt sind (gemäss Anhang 4 der Verordnung über die Verwendung der zweckgebundenen Mineralölsteuer und weiterer für den Strassenverkehr zweckgebundener Mittel ([MinVV]). Die Grundlage für die Liste bildet die Definition des «Raums mit städtischem Charakter» des Bundesamts für Statistik BFS (2012). Dabei wurde die Beitragsberechtigung für alle Gemeinden erhalten, die aufgrund der Agglomerationsdefinition von 2000 beitragsberechtigt waren. Die Anzahl Gürtelgemeinden wurde gegenüber der Definition des BFS von 2012 durch die Anwendung statistischer Kriterien reduziert. Überdies wurden die Gemeinden Sarnen und Appenzell als Kantonshauptorte in die Liste der Beitragsberechtigten Städte und Agglomerationen aufgenommen. Mit Arrondierungen und Lückenfüllungen wurden noch kleine Bereinigungen durchgeführt.</ows:Abstract>
<ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
<ows:LowerCorner>5.140242 45.398181</ows:LowerCorner>
<ows:UpperCorner>11.47757 48.230651</ows:UpperCorner>
</ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
<ows:Identifier>ch.are.agglomerationsverkehr</ows:Identifier>
<ows:Metadata xlink:href="https://www.geocat.ch/geonetwork/srv/ger/md.viewer#/full_view/f4b72bb8-aff0-4eab-b1e8-48e698c0e8fb"/>
<Style>
<ows:Title>Städte und Agglomerationen BeSA</ows:Title>
<ows:Identifier>ch.are.agglomerationsverkehr</ows:Identifier>
<LegendURL format="image/png" xlink:href="https://api3.geo.admin.ch/static/images/legends/ch.are.agglomerationsverkehr_de.png"/>
</Style>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<Dimension>
<ows:Identifier>Time</ows:Identifier>
<Default>current</Default>
<Value>current</Value>
</Dimension>
<TileMatrixSetLink>
<TileMatrixSet>2056_25</TileMatrixSet>
</TileMatrixSetLink>
<ResourceURL format="image/png" resourceType="tile" template="https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/1.0.0/ch.are.agglomerationsverkehr/default/{Time}/2056/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png"/>
</Layer>
...
```

I would like to filter all

```
<ows:Identifier>
```

whcih follow after `<ows:Title>`
eg
ows:Identifierch.are.agglomerationsverkehr</ows:Identifier>

from the document

Was not successfull at all with any tries like

`//Contents/Layer/ows:WGS84BoundingBox/ows:Identifier`

any clues?

Comment: There are more than 1800 ows:Identifier and almost 2100 ows:Title elements. Which one do you need?

Comment: All which begin with ‘ch.’ like in <ows:Identifier>ch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into a namespace problem, and it's not clear to me whether `IMPORTXML` gives you a way to register namespaces. If not, a workaround is necessary:

`//*[local-name() = 'Contents']/*[local-name() = 'Layer']/*[local-name() = 'Identifier']`

Comment: works like a charm , if you subistitute " with ' in your answer `=importxml("https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/EPSG/2056/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml","//*[local-name() = 'Contents']/*[local-name() = 'Layer']/*[local-name() = 'Identifier']")`